# JQuery, Kinetic.js, and MSPointer events (how to addEventListener, or will on() work?)

Tags: jquery, touch, kineticjs, internet-explorer-10

I'm having a heck of a time troubleshooting a little canvas element for touch events on Win8 (specifically the Surface tablet). Apparently it works with the mouse or the stylus, but not with touch. I don't have access to a Win8 touch device to test with, so I'm trying to research this and not coming up with anything definitive.

This is the actual page (using a temporary URL so the site doesn't live on in infamy in the Stack Overflow archives, lol): http://www.urlgone.com/e8e1c2/

The easiest fix appeared to be adding "MSPointerDown" into the jQuery on() function, but the client indicated no change in behavior.

I guess my question is, does jQuery recognize "MSPointerDown" as an event? If it does, then my problem is probably not the function trigger, but something else...

Or could it be in targeting a canvas object? I'm using the Kinetic.js library, and this is my first time working with canvas animations.

EDIT: I think I was posting the wrong code in here, so this is where I'm at with it now.

So, the object that is getting the touch/click/pointer events is this:

```
        var triangle = new Kinetic.Image({
            image: images[key],
            x: tri.x,
            y: tri.y,
            detectionType: "pixel"
        });
```

And this is how I'm trying to trigger it. For normal "click" events, I'm seeing that using jQuery's .on() to bind it works fine, but I get *"Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'addEventListener'"* when I try to use addEventListener on the triangle for normal clicks.

```
            triangle.on("mousedown touchstart click", activateTriangle);
            /*
            // I popped this in here to see if it would work, assuming that if it 
            // doesn't work for clicks, it won't work for pointer events.
            // This gives me the error, 
            // Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addEventListener' 
            triangle.addEventListener('click',function(){
                window.console && console.log('click event');
            });
            // And here's what I get for trying to iterate through it
            // Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addEventListener' wealth-management.php:305
            //  (anonymous function) wealth-management.php:305
            //  e.extend.each jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
            //  e.fn.e.each jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
            //  (anonymous function) wealth-management.php:304
            //  initStage wealth-management.php:318
            //  images.(anonymous function).onload
            $(triangle).each(function(){
                this.addEventListener('click',function(){
                    window.console && console.log('hi');
                });
            });
            */  
        /* Try for IE10 Touch */                
        if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
                window.console && console.log('msPointerEnabled');
                // click to correct info window
                //triangle.on("MSPointerDown",activateTriangle); 
                triangle.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", activateTriangle, false);
        }
```

If I can get addEventListener to work with "click," which I can test without a Win8 touch device, I'm assuming that the addEventListener with "MSPointerDown" will also work. Does that sound about right? How can I attach an eventListener to a Kinetic.js object?

***EDIT***

I couldn't get it working, so instead I have an imagemap of the canvas element that is substituted after a browser check for IE8 or "MSPointerDown." So, ironically, the canvas element will work in IE9 but not IE10. Oh well.

Comment: i can't say for sure right now, but i think that as long as it is not defined as special (to add missing events or fix wrong behavior e.g. `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `focus`, `blur` ) then the given event is directly attached with the native function ( first trying `addEventListener(event, ...)` and using `attachEvent('on'+event, ...)` as fallback. )

Comment: Thanks, I've switched gears to trying to get addEventListener working!

Answer (score 1):

I understand you're using jQuery. I had a similar problem with trying to catch input event coordinates. The problem with jQuery and events is that it synthesises and sanitises its' own event object from the system one which is OK for most cases.
However when jQuery was originally written there were no touch events and therefore it doesn't have the code to trap them.

The MSPointer events do get through but without coordinate information in the $evt structure it generates.

One simple thing you can do in your event listener is use $evt.originalEvent which contains the data from the original Event passed to jQuery.

Where Microsoft is concerned they went their own way as per usual and called the events 'MSPointerDown', MSPointerMove' etc... And you get an event for each finger whaereas The WHATWG way is to use an array of touchpoints in the event structure.